# Replacing a fan switch with 3 black wires with a smart switch

Tags: switch, smart-switch

I have a switch which has a switched hot and an unswitched hot wire (wire attached to the backstab) going through it. I want to replace it with a tp-link Kasa smart switch.

I tried attaching both the load wires to one of the black wires of the smart switch but now some lights don't work until the switch is turned on. I am assuming these lights were going through the unswitched load line.

I have both 2 way and 3 way smart switch (pictures added below for reference.

Need some guidance on how to do this correctly.

[image]

HS200 (2 way) wiring:

[image]

HS210 (3-way) wiring:

[image]

Comment: sounds like 3 way switch

Comment: Please post the exact model of the smart switch, or a wiring diagram.

Comment: @RohitGupta - Added the images for both 2-way and 3-way smart switch that I have.

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box in question please?